# Xamarin Form: Button inside Grid have a margin. How to remove that margin

Tags: button, xamarin, grid, margin

I have a grid contains a set of button. I have set the columnSpacing of the grid to 0 but still have the margin between buttons. I assumed its the button control. Even if I put the margin on button to 0, the result is the same.

I can't use boxView, i need a text and clickable on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, android button has default background drawable that has margin. You can remove it using custom renderer. [Xamarin.Forms custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)

Example:

```
using System;
using test.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(DefaultButtonRenderer))]
namespace test.Droid
{
    public class DefaultButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // Control is Android.Widget.Button, Element is Xamarin.Forms.Button
            if (Control != null && Element != null)
            {
                // remove default background image
                Control.Background = null;

                // set background color
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "BackgroundColor")
            {
                // You have to set background color here again, because the background color can be changed later.
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code will remove button click effect. If you want to remain the effect, you have to set Control.Background to proper resource. (ex: Android.Resource.Attribute.SelectableItemBackground)

Alternatively, you can use label with [TapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/tap/). You can add TapGestureRecognizer to any view.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but I was getting this on my Android platform. Upgrading Xamarin.Forms from 2.5 to recently released 3.1 seems to have resolved it.